# VBA color a variable as double value type

Tags: excel, vba, colors, double

Silly question, I have a variable named "perf" of type double (decimal) in my code.
I basically display the perf in an email and I just want to color my perf in green if positive and red if negative, I have the structure :

```
If perf > 0 Then
    perf.Characters() Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
Else
    perf.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
```

And then I use "perf" in the rest of my code.

Of course it's wrong, I tested some solutions.
Do you have any idea on how to color the result? Should I put "perf" in string using sometghing like Cstr() before?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you want to color it in the email, you'll have to use [`rangeToHtml`](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) and paste the table in the email or use `.HTMLBody` in the outlook email and change the color via html tags.

Comment: A double does not have properties like `Characters` or `Color` or anything else for that matter.

Comment: hey thanks for answering, so should I transform my double in straing for the display ?

Comment: the variable type does not matter. You can't take any formatting actions against a string or a double. You *can* format cells. Or text via html, as I have noted. You'll have to use one of the two solutions I provided. I can't think of any other way to do it.

Comment: yes, eventually I format it directly via html but still, instead  of giving me the perf in number and colored green or red it gives me the word "perf" in green or red ... tha mens it finds the result under the variable perf but instead of disply the result, it display the name of the variable ... 
Here is my code:




strBody = strBody & "id: " & aPosition.id & " / Qty: " & aPosition.QTY & " / Cost: " & aPosition.COST_PRICE & " / Perf: " & " & <span style='font-family:Trebuchet MS,sans-serif;font-size:16;color:#C00000'>perf</span color:#C00000>& "

Answer (score 0):

You are using the string literal "perf" instead of the variable's value:

```vb
    strBody = strBody & "id: " & aPosition.id & " / Qty: " & _
             aPosition.QTY & " / Cost: " & aPosition.COST_PRICE & " / Perf: " & _
          "<span style='font-family:Trebuchet MS,sans-serif;font-size:16;color:#C00000'>" & _
            perf & "</span>"
```